# How to clip text and right align (NOT float) element using CSS2?

Tags: css

[The awesome combination](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) of `white-space: nowrap;`, `overflow: hidden;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in CSS3 does a great job at clipping text of in block element.

I would like to do it with CSS2 (compatible with modern browsers, IE7 and newer), and also align the text (NOT float) to the right. Is it possible?

[Here's a jsFiddle with an example code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/N3WYE/). Please test your answer(s) on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think you can't just set `text-align:right`? Works fine for me.

`white-space` and `text-overflow` are supported in all modern browsers (IE7+). So, in your example, if the right-aligned text extends beyond the parent's width, it will ellipsize.

Here's your fiddle (just pull the window so it's narrower, and you'll see it works fine): http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/N3WYE/2/

Comment: For clipping text, we need to define a width to the block element. That's when the text is getting aligned left. An example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/N3WYE/3/

Comment: @geekpanth3r Okay, so your question *isn't* how to text-overflow w/ text-align right, but how to position a a block to the right. You can position to the right however you want at this point... float to the right, position absolutely to the right, put it in a container and align it the right. Here's a jsfiddle with an inline-block in a container. http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/N3WYE/4/

Comment: @geekpanth3r Perhaps I should have been more explicit. Your text is *not* text-aligned left in your example. The *text is still aligned right*, but your container is *aligned to the left* b/c you gave it a wdith so it no longer spans across the page. So, you want to move your container to the right, which you can do, as i said, by floating ro positioning, which I added in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test this in IE, but displaying the element containing the text as `inline-block` and then setting `text-align: right` on the parent works.

http://jsfiddle.net/N3WYE/1/

Edit: `display: inline` on #breadcrumbs should also work, but you'll obviously lose the `block` effects.

Comment: But there's a problem. It's not as easy as setting `text-align` to the body, because that aligns all elements in the page to the right, and my breadcrumb doesn't have a parent element (I can't edit PHP, that's the problem). Is there an alternative way? (again, on jsFiddle if possible. Thanks!)

Comment: Yes, I know. The reason I used `body` in the fiddle was to avoid adding more HTML. I assumed you had a parent element you could use. You could wrap the `p` in a `div` with JS quite easily, or maybe there's a CSS only solution.